# Firebase Database backup

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi could I have a rollback to my database, 
I have lost my data and I want to retrieve them back is there any way to have them ? 
any help would be appreciated
thank you

Comment: There is nothing anyone on Stack Overflow can do for you here. [Reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help.

Comment: and what is the importance of that ?

Answer (score 1):

Database Backup available with the Blaze plan, if you are not you can't